# Printing only selected columns of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to print contents of grid view control. But I want to skip few columns from printing. Print functionality is working fine, but how to skip few columns of grid view from printing.

Below is my code:

```
PrintHelper.PrintWebControl(grdAppointments );
```

grdAppointments is name of grid view control. It prints all columns of grid, but I want to print only few columns.

Comment: **GirdView.SelectedIndex** member, or **GridView_SelectedIndexChanging** event, didi you tried ?

Comment: what I mean by selected columns is that I want to get only few columns from gridview, and leaving others.

Comment: `protected void MyGridView_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e){
    var column = MyGridView.Columns[e.NewSelectedIndex];
}` use that event and append into a collection your data to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When printing the page-
1) First hide the unwanted columns
2) Then call the print() function
3) Show previously hided columns

You can refer following link to hide the columns

[Hide GridView column using javascript](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2008/03/how-to-hide-gridview-column-using.html)

Comment: this is easiest way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

A non-programmatical solution could be that you create a temporary `grid` and copy all selected columns/items to it, and print that `gridview` data. Then dispose it.

To get selected columns:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedColumns.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.SelectedColumns)
        dataGridView2.Columns.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: That will work fine, but still how to get selected columns from current grid